# How to add powers?

Tags: exponentiation, perfect-powers

> $$5^3 + 5^3 + 5^3 + 5^3 + 5^3= 5^n$$ or $$5\times5^3=5^n$$ or $$125\times5=5^n$$
>   What is $n$?

*P.S.*: I know how to multiply these powers but I've never known about how to add the same power (or multiply it by a number), to get a different power.

I searched the question up, but all it comes up with is "how to simplify like terms". I know that $5^n$ equals $625$ but how can I work out what power that is? (It is $5^4$, but that's not the point of the question.)

The question is, is there some index law that would help me solve this? If not, how do I solve this question anyways? I want some rule such as $a^x+a^y=a^z$, when $x, y, z$ are variables.

Thanks.

Comment: The left side is $5\times 5^3$.

Comment: Hint:  what is $x+x+x+x+x$?

Comment: @Dr.MV That's why I said I never knew how to multiply a number by a power to get a different power. But I'll edit the question to show more working. Thanks

Comment: As Dr. MV wrote:  the left side is $5^1 \times 5^3$.  So.......

Comment: Remember that $x = 1\times x$,  remember that $x = x^1$, remember that $(a+b)\times x = a\times x + b\times x$, and remember that $x^a\times x^b = x^{a+b}$

Comment: Do you mean that you want some function $f$ such that $f_5(3, 3, 3, 3, 3) = 4$?

Comment: @Aroxen I still don't know about functions but if that's what I mean than yes

Comment: @bio It seems like it. If you want a rule that tells you $a^x + a^y = a^z$ when you have $a$, $x$, and $y$, then everyone here seems to be misunderstanding you. I don't believe there's an addition rule for powers in general, unless you do factoring tricks like in this specific case.

Answer (score 4):

Think about it as factoring $5^3$ from the left hand side, so we have:

$$5^3 + 5^3 + 5^3 + 5^3 + 5^3 = 5^3\left(1+1+1+1+1\right) = 5^3(5) = 5^4$$

Answer (score 1):

In reply to your question at the end: the best you can say, in general, is that $$a^x+a^y=a^x(1+a^{y-x})$$

Answer (score 0):

Since repeated addition is simply multiplication, you can define

$\ 5^3 + 5^3 + 5^3$

as

$\ 3(5^3) $

3 can be defined as $\ 5^x $ where  $\ x = log$<sub>5</sub> 3

since powers that are multiplied are added together the expression becomes

5 <sup>3 + log<sub>5</sub>   3</sup>

Therefore $\  c*a^b = a^n$ where $\ n = b + log$ <sub>a</sub>c